Angular - esbuild chunk names
I just upgraded an Angular app from v17 to v18, and during the process I made the move from using webpack to now building with esbuild.
Im trying to understand the code splitting and chunk names with esbuild though.
When I was building with webpack, my build output would use the folder/library name as the chunk name
Initial chunk files           | Names                                |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
main.92475803a5fca8d8.js      | main                                 |   1.42 MB |               273.24 kB
styles.20904db00cf53b80.css   | styles                               | 141.38 kB |                16.59 kB
polyfills.0f3a4437da88979b.js | polyfills                            |  33.53 kB |                10.81 kB
runtime.ba39d907e85687c8.js   | runtime                              |   2.97 kB |                 1.43 kB

                              | Initial total                        |   1.59 MB |               302.06 kB

Lazy chunk files              | Names                                |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
371.9d3e31a503ec5f8b.js       | bevtech-domain-wine-type-mocks       | 625.53 kB |               100.67 kB
159.950ed6c3cf479734.js       | bevtech-app-source-tank-mocks        |  21.41 kB |                 7.57 kB
828.b76b0b426edc2ab7.js       | bevtech-shared-feature-errors        |  15.00 kB |                 4.81 kB
312.9d6d0d453f345efb.js       | bevtech-shared-feature-heartbeat     |   9.79 kB |                 2.77 kB[39m[39m
563.6479fc29093db925.js       | NestedAppAuthController-mjs          |   8.01 kB |                 2.13 kB
common.033a642f4d7c3bcd.js    | common                               |   6.18 kB |                 1.01 kB
805.b65d734ca0645730.js       | bevtech-shared-feature-version       |   6.15 kB |                 2.21 kB
949.a597d12949426514.js       | bevtech-shared-feature-profile       |   5.81 kB |                 1.64 kB
708.5d90869b8eb826ea.js       | bevtech-shared-feature-help          |   5.31 kB |                 1.87 kB
476.7e017a9c5d34cf3e.js       | bevtech-shared-feature-notifications |   4.87 kB |                 1.57 kB
776.d3b4ea7c52ff0412.js       | bevtech-app-source-tank-mocks        | 510 bytes |               277 bytes
688.de53900278fcbe74.js       | bevtech-shared-mocks                 | 356 bytes |               239 bytes
689.511c5a5988140480.js       | bevtech-shared-ui-atoms-icons        | 177 bytes |               123 bytes

But now with esbuild, and without really changing anything else prject wise other than the build executors, the chunk names are all missing or just say "index"
Initial chunk files                       | Names                         |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
main-KWHD6H2S.js                          | main                          |   1.14 MB |               110.58 kB
chunk-JX2ZJQXV.js                         | -                             | 456.58 kB |                91.15 kB
chunk-5CC73DVU.js                         | -                             | 168.01 kB |                49.63 kB
styles-3SWETO6W.css                       | styles                        | 143.41 kB |                17.02 kB
chunk-FEL4DAWO.js                         | -                             |  79.04 kB |                19.57 kB
chunk-3ANSV6VJ.js                         | -                             |  55.63 kB |                15.59 kB
chunk-7APSDC5B.js                         | -                             |  49.65 kB |                14.37 kB
polyfills-6EAL64PA.js                     | polyfills                     |  34.23 kB |                11.13 kB
chunk-QE2GORIC.js                         | -                             |  18.32 kB |                 5.18 kB
chunk-LB44TSLO.js                         | -                             |  15.58 kB |                 5.17 kB
chunk-UVA5YSGE.js                         | -                             |   9.18 kB |                 2.58 kB
chunk-NXR37NKG.js                         | -                             |   8.65 kB |                 2.60 kB
chunk-37B7PM2U.js                         | -                             |   2.49 kB |               964 bytes
chunk-U4SIGHYW.js                         | -                             |   2.25 kB |               901 bytes
chunk-BTQNES4R.js                         | -                             |   1.69 kB |               717 bytes
chunk-OCEG32DO.js                         | -                             |   1.68 kB |               443 bytes
chunk-LFEKHDIL.js                         | -                             |   1.12 kB |               535 bytes
chunk-SOKPGJEH.js                         | -                             | 295 bytes |               295 bytes

                                          | Initial total                 |   2.19 MB |               348.44 kB

Lazy chunk files                          | Names                         |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
src-RMOL7GYA.js                           | index                         | 663.19 kB |               110.88 kB
src-XLEY72BJ.js                           | index                         |  15.44 kB |                 5.01 kB
src-E4TECBBB.js                           | index                         |   6.36 kB |                 1.93 kB
src-VL7AMVCZ.js                           | index                         |   6.30 kB |                 1.82 kB
src-UICMSAO7.js                           | index                         |   5.56 kB |                 1.98 kB
src-5T3SWQ35.js                           | index                         |   4.97 kB |                 1.64 kB
router-F5OFDX6B.js                        | router                        |   2.06 kB |               800 bytes
ngx-markdown-YKWGQXAU.js                  | ngx-markdown                  | 698 bytes |               698 bytes
src-IHKGMIR7.js                           | index                         | 409 bytes |               409 bytes
src-TH4CWI4Q.js                           | index                         | 125 bytes |               125 bytes
BrowserPerformanceMeasurement-XR4JUOF4.js | BrowserPerformanceMeasurement | 113 bytes |               113 bytes


What is driving the chunk names and is there something in the build configuration I can change so that I can get it back to the naming how it used to be, or is that just not possible using esbuild vs webpack?
